# Calculate integral or limit if not exactly solvable

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to calculate:

$$
\int_0^\lambda \arctan \left(\frac{\tanh(x)}{C}\right)dx,
$$

however I cannot find a nice substitution to perform the integral. Does anyone have an idea?

Note: I am not sure whether this integral has a solution. If so, I would be interested in finding the following limit:
$$
\lim_{|\lambda|\rightarrow\infty}\left(-\lambda + \int_0^\lambda \arctan \left(\frac{\tanh(x)}{C}\right)dx \right)
$$
(I am hoping it diverges to $+\infty$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$ \tanh x = 1 - \frac{2e^{-2x}}{1 + e^{-2x}} = 1 + O\left(e^{-2x}\right). $$

Thus

$$ \arctan\left(C^{-1} \tanh x \right) = \arctan\left( C^{-1} + O\left(e^{-2x}\right) \right) = \arctan(C^{-1}) + O\left(e^{-2x}\right). $$

This shows that

$$ \int_{0}^{\lambda} \arctan\left(C^{-1} \tanh x \right) \, dx = \lambda \arctan(C^{-1}) + O(1). $$

Therefore

$$ \lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \left( -\lambda + \int_{0}^{\lambda} \arctan\left(C^{-1} \tanh x \right) \, dx \right)
= \begin{cases}
+\infty, & C^{-1} > \tan 1 \\
\text{converges}, & C^{-1} = \tan 1 \\
-\infty, & C^{-1} < \tan 1
\end{cases} $$

When $C^{-1} = \tan 1$, Mathematica says that the limit will be approximately

$$ -0.50560901153910564220\cdots. $$

Answer (score 1):

For $x$ large, $\tanh (x)$ is just a little less than $1$ and $\arctan (\frac 1C)$ is essentially constant.  The integral will then be of order $\lambda \arctan (\frac 1C)$  The limit will diverge (one way or the other) unless $C=\frac 1{\tan 1}\approx 0.642$